# How to allow blank field on OneToOne serializer field for Django REST Framework API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When POSTing to my API endpoint I get a `field is required` error on a OneToOne field, but I create the OneToOne Field in the save() method of the model I'm POSTing.

I've tried setting `default=None`, `null=True`, and `blank=True`

**Device Model**

```py
class Device(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    brand = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    year_purchased = models.IntegerField()
    serial_number = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    qrcode = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Device, self).save(**kwargs)
        if not self.qrcode:
            self.generate_qrcode()
        if not self.checkouts.exists():
            checkout = Checkout(item=self)
            checkout.save()
```

**Checkout Model**

```py
class Checkout(models.Model):

    status_choices = (...)

    # Fields
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='item', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    checked_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_choices, default=in_stock)

    # Relationship Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        DeviceUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="checkouts",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )

    item = models.OneToOneField(
        Device,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="checkouts",
        primary_key=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

**Device Serializer**

```py
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Device
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'created',
            'last_updated',
            'brand',
            'year_purchased',
            'serial_number',
            'info',
            'checkouts',
        )
```

When POSTing `http POST http://localhost:8000/main/api/device/ brand=test2 info=123213123 name=test2 serial_number=12321321 year_purchased=12 'Authorization: Token .....'`

I expect to get a confirmation that a device was created, instead I get

```
"checkouts": [ "This field is required." ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify **`checkouts`** field to your **`DeviceSerializer`** serializer as,

```
checkouts = serializers.DateTimeField(default=None, source='checkouts.checked_out', read_only=True)
```

```
# code sample
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    checkouts = serializers.DateTimeField(default=None, source='checkouts.checked_out', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Device
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'created',
            'last_updated',
            'brand',
            'year_purchased',
            'serial_number',
            'info',
            'checkouts',
        )
```